# Where do "apt-get install" packages come from?

Tags: apt, package-management

Is there a place (website) to view all packages that can be installed with apt-get, or rather search for one based of some criteria such as key-phrase, similar to what you can do for npm?
Where are these packages that are being installed being stored?
How does someone add a package that can be installed with apt-get?

apt seems like a mystery tool that the only reason people know what packages that can be installed install is because of a forum or Stack Overflow post told them too, where's the master list if there is one?

Comment: If it's a mystery, at least it's a well-documented mystery.  Start with `man apt`, and there should be a complete user guide in `/usr/share/doc/apt/` if you install the `apt-doc` package.   BTW, to search for packages try `apt-cache search`.  and, of course, see [Package Management](https://wiki.debian.org/PackageManagement) on the debian wiki.

Comment: There will not be a "one fits all" solution here, as you can add new repositories which expands the list of available programs.

Comment: Packages.deb, example overview https://packages.debian.org/stable/ → the 40,000 packages are listed in groups. ..... Storage example  http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a place (website) to view all packages that can be installed with apt-get

Look at the locations given in `/etc/apt/sources.list`